# Sort Integers in an array by the number of 1 Bits in each integer

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation, bit

Given an integer array arr. You have to sort the integers in the array in ascending order by the number of 1's in their binary representation and in case of two or more integers have the same number of 1's you have to sort them in ascending order.

Return the sorted array.

> **Input**: arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
> **Output**: [0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,7]
> **Explantion**: [0] is the only integer with 0 bits. [1,2,4,8] all have 1
> bit. [3,5,6] have 2 bits. [7] has 3 bits. The sorted array by bits is
> [0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,7]
>
> **Input**: arr = [1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1] 
> **Output**:
> [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024] 
> **Explantion**: All integers have 1
> bit in the binary representation, you should just sort them in
> ascending order.

So, I used Brian Kernigham's Algorithm here to count the number of 1 bits in each integer present in the array. This is what I've coded so far :-

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortByBits(vector<int>& arr) {
        //firstly sort the input array
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
        
        
        vector<int> count;
        //Using Brian Kernigham's Algorithm
        for(int i =0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            while(arr[i]){
                arr[i] = arr[i] & (arr[i] -1);
                count[i] ++;
            }
        } 
    }
};
```

But, I don't know how to combine the `count[]` array and the input array, `arr[]` to get the output. I thought of using `map()` STL of C++ but since the function needs to return `vector<int>`, I dropped the thought of it.
Can somebody provide the further solution to it? Also, please don't share any code which uses the pre-defined function `builtin_popcount()`

Comment: "please don't share any code which uses the pre-defined function builtin_popcount()" why not? Thats the functionality you already have, given some code that does the sorting by using the builtin it should be possible to replace that by your counting function

Comment: Does [`std::bitset::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) count as pre-defined as well?

Comment: Incidentally, it's brian kernighaN.

Comment: Why not create a comparison function which compares two integer values, and return true if the first is "smaller" (have less one-bits) than the second, and then pass it to `std::sort` to use as the comparison function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because then the function to count bits has to be called more than necessary. Well its a trade-off, I choose a different one for my answer

Comment: You can always sort an array of indices, using `count[i]` as the main key, and `arr[i]` in case two elements have the same count. Then you have two temporary arrays, but only need to sort once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (but not most efficient) is to store the numbers and the counts together in a container, sort that, and the extract the numbers:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortByBits(vector<int>& arr) {
        vector<std::pair<int,int> temp;
        
        for(int i =0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            int count = 0;
            while(arr[i]){
                arr[i] = arr[i] & (arr[i] -1);
                count++;
            }
            temp.emplace_back(count,arr[i]);
        } 
       
        std::sort(temp.begin(),temp.end());   

        // extract the numbers again:
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        // ...
        return numbers;
    }
};
```

`std::sort` is not stable, so if you first sort the numbers and then sort again for the number of set bits, you would have to use `std::stable_sort`. On the other hand, `std::pair<int,int>` does have a `operator<` that can be used with `std::sort` to sort according to `first` and then `second`.

Alternatively you could write a comparator that lets you sort the numbers. This will not have all the unnecessary copying like the above, but it will call the function to count the bits more than necessary:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortByBits(vector<int>& arr) {
       std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int a,int b) {
               // count bits here
               auto n_bits_a = count_bits(a);
               auto n_bits_b = count_bits(b);
               if (n_bits_a == n_bits_b) return a < b;
               return n_bits_a < n_bits_b; });
        return arr;
    }
};
```

The comparator can be written more compact if again we use the fact that `std::pair<int,int>` already has the desired ordering:

```
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int a,int b) {
    auto proj = [](int x) { return std::pair<int,int>{ count_bits(x),x}; };
    return proj(a) < proj(b);
});
```

It is not completely clear, why the function takes the vector by reference *and* returns a vector. The above also sorts the parameter.

Comment: Possibly `[](int lhs, int rhs) {return std::pair{count_bits(lhs), lhs} < std::pair{count_bits(rhs), rhs};}`. (some people wrote wrongly the if condition making the comparer invalid).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I considered it but thought the longwinded would be easier for OP. Anyhow, I added it now

Comment: I personally have to read twice the long-winded version. I even prefer the range version with *projection*, so, inside comparer (when we don't have range): `auto proj = [](int i){ return std::pair{count_bits(i), i}; }; return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs);`. (and with range: `ranges::sort(arr, std::less<>{}, [](int i){ return std::pair{count_bits(i), i}; })`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I like the projection and stole it for the answer, but I am not fluent enough with `ranges` to include it in my answers

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), which makes working with bits easier. `std::bitset` has a `count()` function that returns the number of bits set to 1, and you can use this in comparator function you provide `std::sort()`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<int> sortByBits(std::vector<int>& arr) {
        std::vector<int> vec = arr;

        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            [](int a, int b) { 
                std::bitset<32> ba(a);
                std::bitset<32> bb(b);
                if (ba.count() == bb.count())
                    return a < b;
                else
                    return ba.count() < bb.count();
            });

        return vec;
    }
    
};
```

Here's a [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oaohb8).

Comment: Same remarks as for idclev-463035818, comparing pair/tuple avoids some potential issue (especially for beginners).